# Laravel Resource append locally modified attributes

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to return a model's `Resource` while appending a local change to some attributes that already exist in the model (in a way that it does not change database values). What is the correct method to call to achieve this (because `append` function is not correct)?

```
// exists $model->currency
// Version: Laravel 7.x
// ModelResoruce is a Illuminate/Http/JsonResource

$tempCurrency = $this->findCurrecy($model->currency);

return ok(ModelResource::make($model)->append(['currency' => $tempCurrency, /* multiple dynamic changes*/]);

// updated: more real scenario:
// $localized has MANY dynamic keys that exist in model but MAYBE different values

$localized= ['currency' => 'x', 'name' => 'y',]; 


ok(ModelResource::make($model)->append($localized);

// I want: user will see temp but data is not modified
// What happens: append does not change currency's value
```

Answer (score 1):

This won't modify the database:

```
$tempCurrency = $this->findCurrecy($model->currency);
$model->currency = $tempCurrency;
```

As long as you don't call `save()` on `$model` later on, the database won't be affected.

Comment: okay nice but it is actually some variables that can be different from time to time: I mean imagine currency and name one time and currency, name and title other time. so it is an array of fields.